# Better Way To Edit A View Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, model-binding

I actually came up with a working example of how to display (GET) and edit (POST) a view model consisting of three models in MVC.  However, my MVC skills are limited and I was looking for suggestions on "the right way" I should be doing this.
The part in question is that I'm sending the form fields back individually rather than to a view model, which is something I couldn't figure out how to do.

Here are my models

**Name**

```
public partial class Name
{
    public Name()
    {
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
        this.Emails = new HashSet<Email>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

**Address**

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int ADDRESS_ID { get; set; }
    public int NameID { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS_1 { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }

    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Email**

```
public partial class Email
{
    public int EMAIL_ID { get; set; }
    public int NameID { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }

    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
}
```

**My View Model made up of all the fields from the three models.**

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS_1 { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
}
```

**The GET method of the Edit page (in the Controller)**

```
    // GET: Names/Edit/5
    //The GET method takes the id from the URL and passes it into the query to return data for the specific record
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //This query is an outer join of the Name, Address and Email models/tables
        var query = from n in db.Names
                    join a in db.Addresses
                    on n.ID equals a.NameID into na
                    from a in na.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join e in db.Emails
                    on n.ID equals e.NameID into ne
                    from e in ne.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where n.ID == id
                    //Creates a new instance of the view model, populated with the query data
                    select new ContactFormViewModel
                    {
                        ID = id,
                        FIRST_NAME = n.FIRST_NAME,
                        LAST_NAME = n.LAST_NAME,
                        ADDRESS_1 = a.ADDRESS_1,
                        CITY = a.CITY,
                        STATE = a.STATE,
                        ZIP = a.ZIP,
                        EMAIL = e.EMAIL
                    };

        //Returns the query to the view
        return View(query);
    }
```

**The POST method of the Edit page (in the Controller)**

```
    // POST: Names/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //The POST method takes the individual form field data and passes it to queries that update all three models separately 
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string FIRST_NAME, string LAST_NAME, string ADDRESS_1, string CITY, string STATE, string ZIP, string EMAIL)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Query the database for the row to be updated. 
            var queryN =
                from n in db.Names
                where n.ID == id
                select n;

            var queryA =
                from a in db.Addresses
                where a.NameID == id
                select a;

            var queryE =
                from e in db.Emails
                where e.NameID == id
                select e;

            //Assign the form field data to the fields in the model 
            foreach (Name n in queryN)
            {
                n.FIRST_NAME = FIRST_NAME;
                n.LAST_NAME = LAST_NAME;
            }

            //If there are no address records, insert
            if (!queryA.Any())
            {
                //New instance of Address
                var address = new Address
                {
                    NameID = id,
                    ADDRESS_1 = ADDRESS_1,
                    CITY = CITY,
                    STATE = STATE,
                    ZIP = ZIP

                };
                db.Addresses.Add(address);
            }
            //Else, if there are address records, then update
            else
            {
                foreach (Address a in queryA)
                {
                    a.ADDRESS_1 = ADDRESS_1;
                    a.CITY = CITY;
                    a.STATE = STATE;
                    a.ZIP = ZIP;
                }
            }

            //If there are no email records, insert
            if (!queryE.Any())
            {
                //New instance of Email
                var email = new Email
                {
                    NameID = id,
                    EMAIL = EMAIL
                };
                db.Emails.Add(email);
            }
            //Else, if there are email records, then update
            else
            {
                foreach (Email e in queryE)
                {
                    e.EMAIL = EMAIL;
                }
            }


            //// Submit the changes to the database. 
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                // Provide for exceptions.
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**The View**

```
@model IQueryable<MDTestApplication.ViewModel.ContactFormViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <hr />

        @*Uses foreach loop to get all field data from the view model*@
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.FIRST_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*Using razor syntax to output the value*@
                    @*Using form field 'Name' attribute for posting back to the controller*@
                    <input type="text" name="FIRST_NAME" value="@item.FIRST_NAME" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.LAST_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="LAST_NAME" value="@item.LAST_NAME" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ADDRESS_1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="ADDRESS_1" value="@item.ADDRESS_1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.CITY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="CITY" value="@item.CITY" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.STATE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="STATE" value="@item.STATE" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ZIP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="ZIP" value="@item.ZIP" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.EMAIL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="EMAIL" value="@item.EMAIL" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

    }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's additional insert and update code I added to Alex's answer below.  You would use this same setup for address and email.

```
foreach (var address in model.Addresses)
    {
        var addressToUpdate = name.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => AddressId== address.AddressId);
        if (addressToUpdate != default(Address))
        {
            // preform an update
            addressToUpdate.AddressId = address.AddressId;
            addressToUpdate.City = address.City;
            addressToUpdate.State = address.State;
            addressToUpdate.Zip = address.Zip;                           
        }
        else
        {
            //perform an insert
            var newAddress = new Address
            {
                NameID = model.ID,
                Address1 = address.Address1,
                City = address.City,
                State = address.State,
                Zip = address.Zip
            };
            db.Addresses.Add(newAddress);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameter in your `Edit()` method to your `ViewModel` type? If the property names are the same, the `ModelBinder` will try to map it automagically.

Comment: Also, why are you using _some_ `HtmlHelper` methods and not others? For instance, you use `LabelFor` and not `EditorFor`? Let razor do the work of generating the markup. It is less error prone.

Comment: The view model I have isn't made up of the three other models.  It's just a listing of the fields that happen to be in those models, so there's really nothing to map to if the parameter is the view model type.
I tried an alternate version using a view model set up that way, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: As for the HtmlHelpers in the view.  That's just left over from the scaffolded version that was automatically created.  I used that to start with and manipulated it to work with my view model instead.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your setup. Have you looked at some of the tutorials on http://asp.net? The [Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1) is a great one to start on and it should give a better idea of how/where to start.

Comment: I was hoping for someone to elaborate on what exactly is "wrong".
I have tried that tutorial and various others, but I can take another look.  Finding something that edits multiple models is not easy.

Comment: Basically, when you're editing multiple complex objects in one view, you'll need to nest them and make sure that the `name` attributes correctly map up to your object structure. Then you can let the `ModelBinder` handle the rest.

Comment: why are you taking a one to many relationship and flattening it down to a one to one for the view?

Comment: If you are around and want some direction, I made a chatroom where we can discuss your issue and potential solutions.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76199/asp-net-mvc-c-model-binding

Comment: Claies - The models were automatically built when I pulled SQL tables into Entity Framework.  I just left them as they were.
There's no reason for what I did, other than I don't know any better at this point.  This was my first successful attempt to get a form to post to multiple models.  I know enough to realize that there's got to be a more proper way.  That's what I'm looking for.
I would think a form posting to multiple tables would be a very common thing, that finding examples wouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all let me start with the naming convention.

This:

```
public int ADDRESS_ID { get; set; }
public int NameID { get; set; }
```

Is **BAD** You have no naming convention at all, some properties are PascalCase, others capital case with underscores. I strongly advise you to install some tool that will enforce you to apply set of style and consistency rules(for example [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/)). In general it is very common to use PascalCase for properties.

Once you apply it your models will look like:

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int NameId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
}
```

Second thing:
If I understand correct you are trying to edit a data for one user:
His(or hers) first and last name, list of addresses and a lit of emails. If I am right both your View and ViewModel are wrong. Your ViewModel could look as following:

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    public int NameId { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }      
    public IList<Emails> { get; set; }
}
```

Controller(**UPDATED**):

```
// GET: Names/Edit/5
//The GET method takes the id from the URL and passes it into the query to 

//return data for the specific record
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //You don't need the joins since you have navigation properies!
        var name = db.Names.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == id);
        ContactFormViewModel model;
        if(name == default(Name))
        {
            model = new ContactFormViewModel{
                 Addresses = new List<Address>(),
                 Emails = new List<Email>()
            };
        }
        else {
            model = new ContactFormViewModel
            {
                     NameId = name.NameId ,
                     FirstName = name.FirstName,
                     LastName = name.LastName ,
                     Addresses = name.Addresses.ToList(),
                     Emails = name.Emails.ToList(),
             };
        } 
        if(!model.Addresses.Any())
        {
            model.Addresses.Add(new Address());
        }
        if(!model.Emails.Any())
        {
            model.Emails.Add(new Email());
        }
        //Returns the query to the view
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
    @model MDTestApplication.ViewModel.ContactFormViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Name</h4>
            <hr />


             @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NameId)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })             
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "FirstName" })
                    </div>          
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })              
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => item.LastName, new { @class = "FirstName" })
                    </div>          
                </div>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Addresses[i].AddressId)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addresses[i].Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })             
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses[i].Address1, new { @class = "FirstName" })
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addresses[i].City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })             
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses[i].City, new { @class = "FirstName" })
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                    /// Continue here with all the address properties
                }

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Emails.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Emails[i].EmailId)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Emails[i].Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })               
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Emails[i].Email, new { @class = "FirstName" })
                        </div>          
                    </div>              
                }
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

Edit Action in Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(ContactFormViewModel model)
    {   
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Query the database for the row to be updated. 
            var name = db.Names.FirstOrDefault( n => n.NameId == model.NameId);
            if(name != default(Name))
            {
                name.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                name.LastName = model.LastName;
                bool hasAddresses = name.Addresses.Any();
                foreach(var address in model.Addresses)
                {
                    var addressToUpdate = name.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId == address.AddressId);
                    if(addressToUpdate != default(Address))
                    {
                       // preform an update
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //perform an insert
                    }
                }

                foreach(var email in model.Emails)
                {
                    var emailToUpdate = name.Emails.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmailId == email.EmailId);
                    if(emailToUpdate != default(Email))
                    {
                       // preform an update
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //perform an insert
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll look through all of this.
Disregard the casing.  That's not the issue here.  I'm just working on learning the functionality right now.  Not looking to put something into production.

Comment: Alex - it looks like you understand very well what I'm trying to do.  How would you write out the updates and inserts to Address and Email in the controller in your version?

Comment: In general the way that you did update and inset in your code is fine. As an alternative you can use some mapping library such as AutoMapper or ValueInjecter that will make it easier for you to copy all the property values to an updated object

Comment: Alex - trying to work with all of this now, but there's a little confusion.  First in the ViewModel, you're using NameId.  That's the name of the foreign key in the Address and Email tables.  Are you intending this to be ID from the Name table?

Comment: Yes this is supposed to be an Id from the Name table

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I finally got this to work.  I'll accept your solution if you can clean up some of the code in your view for other users.  Please remove "IQueryable" from the model declaration at the top of the page.  Also, please replace the word "item" with model from the view.  Example - model => item.FirstName. (I deleted my previous comments of errors caused from these)

Comment: Actually I do have a final issue. The Email or Address input fields are not shown for records without an address or email, therefore, the insert code can never run. Think of this like an outer join, where I still want Address and Email fields to show up even if null (so I can still type something in to be saved).  Thanks

Comment: Updated the view. Also take a look at the controller code. In case that user have no Addresses or Emails, simply add an empty Address/Email so it could be rendered in the view

Comment: Looks like there's still some adjustments needed.  In your if statements  `if(!Addresses.Any())`, **Addresses** is not available in that scope.  Should this somehow be tied in with `bool hasAddresses = name.Addresses.Any();` which you are using in the edit Action?  You declare that there, but never use it for anything.

Comment: It should be model.Addresses.Any()

Comment: Got it all now.  Thanks a lot.  I'm going to put up the insert and update code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is submit a variable length list, which is not something asp mvc can handle on its own.  Let me explain:

You have a form, and inside the form is a foreach loop that creates editable fields for multiple records.  ASP MVC can handle updating a single record just fine with its form helpers, however when you have multiple records that need updating, ASP MVC doesn't automatically create an indexing number for each record, which makes it impossible for it to keep track of which property belongs to which record.  When you submit the form, MVC doesn't create this indexing for you, so you need to find alternative solutions.

I highly suggest you look at this blog and incorporate the helper that is provided to achieve your form submission:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: that may help better model things, but the problem really seems to be that in their ViewModel they have flattened their lists; e.g. they have `ICollection<Email> Emails` in the Model but `string Email` in the ViewModel.

Comment: This is simply not true. Mvc handles lists just fine. You just need to let it do its thing. This involves not doing foreachs yourselves but doing Html.EditorFor the list property.